# jquery.get() error 404 - how get url of the file that was not found?

Tags: jquery, get

I have the following code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < file_names.length; ++i) {
        promises.push(file_names[i]);
        promises.push(Jquery.get(images_path + file_names[i]), null, null, "text"));
    }
```

Sometime file doesn't exist or maybe another error can happen. In case of error 404 I get this error text.

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!doctype html><title>404 Not Found</title><h1 style=\"text-align: center\">404 Not Found</h1><hr/><p style=\"text-align: center\">PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3</p>","status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

How can I know which file was not found? I'd like to print to the user this info.

Comment: if you know which promise it was, then the file name is the previous element of the `promises` array.

Answer (score 0):

When 404 is returned, the actual file `file_names[i]` should contain the file name.